# Laravel 5.3 SQL Server Migration error

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I have a migration error with accessing a sql server using laravel 5.3.

*Using Windows 10 with WAMP, also need to point out that I have the necessary php extensions:

1. php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86
2. php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86

I dumped some data from the database in my view, meaning i have access to the database tables, but I cannot run migration commands. I finally found this article that can help me but the problem is that I am not familiar with SQL servers.. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15841
The error when i run a migrate command in image below

[image]

I have done some reading and I know that sysobjects is like the main table that houses all information about the database.. and after reading the article i am i found the SQLGrammer class but I am still not sure what i am doing.. Can anyone help?

This is my .env

[image]

Comment: Do you have all the correct database connection settings in your .env?

Comment: yes i do, I will put it up on with an edit

Comment: Bear in mind that the *command line* PHP may have a different INI file from the *web server* PHP—are you absolutely sure that you've got the SQL Server driver installed and configured in *both*? Check the documentation for your PHP installation (WAMP?) to make certain you're changing the right config. Check with `php -i`. Is mssql listed under PDO drivers there? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827884/php-ini-command-line-php-and-wamp-server-access-different-files

Comment: @MattGibson Wow that was it!!!

Comment: @MattGibson I get another error Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll'

Comment: Now that i see it like that I dont think sqlsrv_7 should be there

Comment: Just checked for extension in php56 and php7 folders and they are all there. Why does is look for sqlsrv_7.dll inside php56 folder?

Comment: ignore that, those are warnings not errors! Thanks a lot @MattGibson Ill post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Matt Gibson in the comments, for giving me this link. I just copied the SQL Server driver installed extensions in the 2 PHP.ini file, the 1 in apache and the other in PHP thanks a lot!!

[php.ini - command line PHP and WAMP server access different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827884/php-ini-command-line-php-and-wamp-server-access-different-files)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the `pdo_mysql.so` extension? Make sure it is enabled using `phpinfo()`

Be sure to configure the DEFAULT key in app/config/database.php and in .env file.

Make sure mysql is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

If nothing works, it would be nice if you show us how your
`app/config/database.php` looks like and your `.env`.

Comment: I am using WAMP SERVER 3. on Windows 10

Comment: I have included the .env screenshot

Comment: Note that the question is about SQL Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `sqlsrv` config to the `connections` array in config/database.php?

Since you've added the connections settings in your .env, it should have an entry after mysql / psql etc. similar to this:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
   'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
   'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'), 
   'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
   'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database'),
   'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
   'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
   'prefix' => '',
],
```

You also have to specify the default connection in config/database.php:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
```