# How to use ftp_connect in symfony Command class

Tags: php, symfony

How can I use an ftp function in symfony command. In a controller the ftp functions are working fine. But not in the execute function my command class. I get the following error message.

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException]
>     Attempted to call function "ftp_connect" from the global namespace.

I have the extension loaded in `php.ini`. And as I have already mention it is working in controllers but not in Command classes

Comment: Which `php.ini`? If you run PHP from command line you have to edit `php.ini` for `CLI`.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, PHP has at least 3 types of configuration.

- command line aka. CLI
- apache2
- FPM

I think that you have added ftp module in apache or FPM config, but you probably forgot to add it in CLI config.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention that I am using WampServer on windows 10. I have the un-comment the line extension=php_ftp.dll. I have the ftp enabled in my phpInfo.php list.

Comment: Ok, are you sure that you have enabled in both php config files (apache and cli)? This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/13828024/3827004

Comment: class JobsCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('xoserver:download:jobs');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

     $con =  ftp_connection('xxx.xx.xx.xx');
    }
}  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException]
  Attempted to call function "ftp_connect" from the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks guyz. I have extension=php_ftp.dll line in few php.ini files. It is working now.