# i update the wamp server and error comes in laravel project ([PDOException] could not find driver)?

Tags: php, laravel

after updating the server getting this error while running the command :

> > php artisan migrate:install

**Error**

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = test and table_name = migrations)


  [PDOException]
  could not find driver
```

struck in this .....
search a lot but didn't get the solution.
please anyone help in this please

Comment: Check whether PDO extension is enabled or not.

Comment: extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll   enabled already in php.ini

Comment: check [php.ini - command line PHP and WAMP server access different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827884/php-ini-command-line-php-and-wamp-server-access-different-files). Apache and cli use different **php.ini** file. For artisan commands you need to check if pdo is enabled in cli php.ini. In command prompt type `php -i | find /i "Configuration File"` to see location

Comment: thanks, a lot man no word's for you write  this in answer ...once again thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Follow these steps:**

- Open "php.ini" (Find where you installed php mine "C:/php7")
- Find the line `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` (If you using notepad use <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>)
- Uncomment the line removing the `#` symbol

**Tip:**

You can find location `php.ini` file using this command `php -i | find /i "Configuration File"`

Comment: Bro I haven't php_pdo_mysql.dll. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The error could not find driver - PDO Exception in XAMPP

1. Open 'php.ini' form xampp control panel.
2. You can find location php.ini file using this command php -i | find /i "Configuration File"
3. Search or find for php_pdo_mysql.dll
4. remove the ';' (semicolon) in the begging of php_pdo_mysql.dll
5. save php.ini and restart apache
6. As you can see now the error is fixed.

Please should be considered DSN in PDO php

// dsn - data source name
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".$this->servername.";dbname=".$this->dbname.";charset=".$this->charset;

Database Connection code in PDO

```
<?php

class dbh
{
    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;
    private $charset;

    public function connect()
    {
        $this->servername = "localhost";
        $this->username = "root";
        $this->password = "";
        $this->dbname = "test";
        $this->charset = "utf8mb4";

        // dsn - data source name
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".$this->servername.";dbname=".$this->dbname.";charset=".$this->charset;


        try {
            // PDO - Represents a connection between PHP and a database server.
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // If any error occurrs catch function catch the errors.
            return $pdo;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            // PDOException
            echo "Connection failed: ".$e->getMessage(). '<br/>Code: '.$e->getCode();
            // Exception::getMessage - gets the Exception message
        }
    }
}
```

[enter link description here](https://www.itofnajathi.com/2019/07/how-to-fix-error-could-not-find-driver.html)